# Can I always interpret a definite integral as a constant?

Tags: real-analysis

For example, this problem

$$I = \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\int_a^bf(x) dx}{x^2}$$

Could I simply write:

$$I = \left[{\int_a^bf(x) dx}\right] \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{1}{x^2} = + \infty$$

Comment: Yes. It is just a number (if it is finite).

Comment: In actual writing, please try to avoid using dummy variables that conflict with "external" variables.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. The reason I wrote it like that was to emphasize that the dummy variable doesn't matter (for myself). I'm new to analysis but I'm starting to think that beginning calculus students (and I was one) aren't always taught that definite integrals are integrating over a dummy variable.

Comment: The constant could be $=0$, in which case the limit in question is $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. A definite integral (if it is finite) is just a way to write down a number so that anyone knows which number we are talking about.

The same goes for $\pi$ etc. Just convenient ways to denote the same number everywhere.

---

For your case: it is not strictly prohibited, but kind of a bad style to use the same *bound variable* $x$ for both, the integral and the limit. Note that

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bf(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$

This means you should prefer writing your limit as

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\int_a^bf(y)\,\mathrm dy}{x^2}$$

and the ambiguity is gone.

---

Finally it is important that even when you know your integral represents a number, you should always keep in mind that you may not know what number it is numerically. This is important because some rules of mathematics only a apply to certain numbers. For example

$$\lim \alpha x_n=\alpha\lim x_n$$

will hold (and only makes sense) if $\lim x_n$ converges in the first place. But if it does not converge neither does $\lim \alpha x_n$, right? *Wrong*! The value $\alpha$ could be zero which makes

$$\lim \alpha x_n=\lim 0=0,$$

hence convergent, while $\alpha \lim x_n$ might not be defined at all. This especially applies to your example:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\int_a^b f(y)\,\mathrm dy}{x^2} = \left[\int_a^bf(y)\,\mathrm dy\right]\cdot\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac 1{x^2}$$

does not really make sense because $\lim_{x\to 0^+}1/x^2$ does not converge. Well, we can rescue the situation a bit by using the limit $+\infty$ and the rule $\alpha\cdot\infty=\infty$, right? Again, if the integral is zero or negative, this will give you *wrong* results.

**Conclusion**: do not use any rules which only work for certain number *if* you do not know the number because it is given implicitely (e.g. by an integral). First compute the number or its relevant properties (if possible).